# Alterar nome do arquivo baixado usando Alamofire

Tags: ios, alamofire

Estou desenvolvendo um app iOS onde atualizo baixando o arquivo JSON com os novos dados, esse arquivo gerado pelo PHP

```
let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory)

Alamofire.download(MINHA_URL.PHP, to: destination).response { response in
     print(response)
}
```

Ele está baixando o arquivo com o nome do arquivo PHP (MINHA_URL.PHP), como faço para renomear esse arquivo para "teste.json"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785555/setting-alamofire-custom-destination-file-name-instead-of-using-suggesteddownloa